# Сортировка массива по количеству вхождений java

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

**Здравствуйте, решаю задачу. Но не могу никак решить ее полностью и корректно.**

Условие:
Дан массив с целыми числами.

```
1.Отобразить для каждого числа количество его вхождений в массив.
2.Числа должны быть отсортированы в порядке убывания количества вхождений.
3. Числа с одинаковым количеством вхождений должны быть отсортированы по убыванию. 
4.Вывести на экран в формате "число - количествоВхождений"
```

Пункт 4 у меня не реализован.

***Можно ли решить эту задачу проще, элегантнее?***
*Ну и 4-й пункт тоже как-то реализовать надо*

```
package Test;

import java.util.*;

public class СортировкаМассиваПоЗначениям {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] array = {1, 2, 4, 12, 3, 4, 4, 3, 89, 1, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7};

    //узнаем количество вхождений
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (map.containsKey(array[i]))
            map.put(array[i], map.get(array[i]) + 1);
        else map.put(array[i], 1);
    }

    //отсортируем массив по значениям
    List list = new ArrayList((map.entrySet()));
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
            return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
        }
    });

    /*
    Вывод с сортировкой по значениям
    4=3
    5=3
    7=3
    1=2
    3=2
    2=1
    12=1
    89=1
 Вместо "=" должно быть "-"
*/
    for (Object loly : list) {
        System.out.println(loly);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конце сделай так:

for (Object loly : list) {

```
        String str = loly.toString();
        System.out.println(str.replace('=', '-'));
    }
```

Comment: Благодарю, а не можете подсказать, эту задачу можно решить как то элегантнее? Проще?

Comment: В вашем коде меня лично все устраивает. Как то элегантнее: вопрос относительный. Поэкспериментируйте!

Comment: Может быть хотя бы напишите как бы это решили Вы, что бы вы использовали? Подтолкните пожалуйста. Спасибо. 
Пытался решить с помощью обычных циклов, Узнавал кол-во вхождений. Но после этого входил в ступор, все в моей голове сводится к карте.

Comment: Не такой уж я крутой кодер, чтобы сходу дать другое решение ))))